# Django Rest Framework - Unable to UPDATE Table Via AJAX through PUT HTTP Method

Tags: django, ajax, api, django-rest-framework, ajaxform

I have a small project where I have built an API and it feeds the frontend via ajax. All the other CRUD functions work apart from UPDATE. When I use Postman, the UPDATE API works perfectly. So I'm guessing the problem is on the ajax side. I have searched for a solution to no avail. Some help on this would be highly appreciated.

My model

```
from django.db import models

CATEGORY = [
    ('Electronics', ('Electronics')),
    ('Furniture', ('Furniture')),
    ('Toys', ('Toys')),
    ('Hardware', ('Hardware')),
    ('Medicine', ('Medicine')),
    ('Groceries', ('Groceries'))
]

# Create your models here.
class Products(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=CATEGORY)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Products"
```

My serializer

```
from .models import Products
from rest_framework import serializers

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = '__all__'
```

Here is my UPDATE API

```
@api_view(['PUT'])
def EditProductAPI(request, id):
    product = Products.objects.get(id=id)
    serializer = ProductSerializer(instance=product, data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_304_NOT_MODIFIED)
```

My Update From

```
<!-- Edit Product Modal -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="modal fade" id="editProduct" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit Product</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form id="editProduct" action="">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <input type="hidden" id="Myid" value="">
                            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                            <label for="p-name">Product Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="p-name" name="name" placeholder="Product Name" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                                <label for="p-category">Category</label>
                                <select class="form-control form-select" aria-placeholder="Category" id="p-category" name="category" required>
                                    <option selected disabled>Category</option>
                                    <option value="Electronics">Electronics</option>
                                    <option value="Furniture">Furniture</option>
                                    <option value="Toys">Toys</option>
                                    <option value="Hardware">Hardware</option>
                                    <option value="Medicine">Medicine</option>
                                    <option value="Groceries">Groceries</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                                <label for="p-quantity">Quantity</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="p-quantity" name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                                <label for="p-price">Price</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="p-price" name="price" placeholder="Price" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="p-edit">Save changes</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My Update AJAX code

```
//Save Edited Product Button
$('#p-edit').click(function(){
    let id = $("#Myid").attr("value");
    console.log(id);
    let myurl = "http://localhost:8000/api/products/edit/"+id+"/";

    $.ajax({
        type : 'PUT',
        url : myurl,
        data : {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val(),
            name: $('input[name=name]').val(),
            category:$('select[name=category]').val(),
            quantity:$('input[name=quantity]').val(),
            price:$('input[name=price]').val()
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            alert("Product Updated!");
            location.reload();
        },
        error:function(data){
            alert("error");
        }
    })
});
```

This is the only error (304) I can see when I try to update a product's details

```
[06/Oct/2021 02:08:20] "GET /api/products/ HTTP/1.1" 200 732
[06/Oct/2021 02:12:33] "GET /api/products/6/ HTTP/1.1" 200 76
[06/Oct/2021 02:12:39] "PUT /api/products/edit/6/ HTTP/1.1" 201 76
[06/Oct/2021 02:12:39] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 8969
[06/Oct/2021 02:12:40] "GET /static/js/script.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[06/Oct/2021 02:12:41] "GET /api/products/ HTTP/1.1" 200 732
```

UPDATE:

I figured it out!! The query function for updating wasn't recognizing new input data. so I changed the data dictionary and used

```
data : $("#editProduct :input").serializeArray(),
```

and the click part as well to

```
$('#editProduct').on('submit', function(e){}
```

it works like a charm.

Comment: What error do you get? A 404? Or is the serializer failing?

Comment: If you open your browser's developer tools, go to the Network tab, then perform the AJAX request, do you see a non-200 status code there? If there's an error, what's the error?

Comment: @BrianD in the Django server I'm getting this "GET /static/js/script.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0.

Comment: @NickODell I'm not getting an error in the in the console section nor the network tab. But in the Django server I'm getting this "GET /static/js/script.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0

Comment: Does `console.log(id)` shows any id?

Comment: Based on `"PUT /api/products/edit/6/ HTTP/1.1" 201`, it seems it made it to the endpoint. Maybe check the request data if it actually had different values for the object?

Comment: @RezaHeydari yes it shows 6 in the console area.

Comment: @BrianD could you please elaborate on your point. I have provided my model as well. I'm not sure if the price attribute might be be problem. I have never dealt with DecimalField before so I'm not sure updating decimals might be the issue.

Comment: `PUT /api/products/edit/6/ HTTP/1.1" 201` this log means there was a put request on the said url, and it returned a 201 response which seems to indicate the update api succeeded. Maybe you don't see any updates because the request data is exactly the same as your object? Try to print `request.data` in your view to see if your view receives correct values

Comment: @BrianD I did as you recommended. Product 6 in this case is as follow { "name": Wood Plunks, "category": "Hardware", "quantity": 10, "price": "500.00" } but upon changing the product name to Nails. This is what I get <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['{{ csrf_token }}'], 'name': ['Wood Plunks'], 'category': ['Hardware'], 'quantity': ['10'], 'price': ['500.00']}>. You are right the data isn't changing after updating. What could be causing this?

Comment: That means it's an issue with the jquery right? Maybe try to use `data: $("#editProduct").serialize(),` instead of specifying each field one by one manually

Comment: @BrianD it has returned an empty {}. I have taken the liberty of putting my entire code on my GitHub page. Here is the project link (https://github.com/steve-njuguna-k/Django-Ajax-CRUD/tree/master) if you could check this out, mostly the jQuery part and get back to me, I would so much appreciate the time and effort in helping me out with this. And anyone else who would like to contribute as well. Thanks.

Comment: @BrianD @Nick Odell @Reza Heydari I figured it out!! The query function for updating wasn't recognizing new input data. so I changed the data dictionary and used `data : $("#editProduct :input").serializeArray(),` and the click part as well to `$('#editProduct').on('submit', function(e){}` it works like a charm.